# When I installed Ubuntu to replace Windows 7, I could nolonger see my Backup disk D and all my data seems to be lost. Can I recover the data?

Tags: installation

I first installed Ubuntu and I used it alongside Windows and it was okey! Later my windows got issues and I installed again windows 7. After this I could no longer boot with ubuntu. So I decided to installed again hoping it would again work peacefully alongside windows. This time however ubuntu did not give me the option of co-existing with windows, but I went on with the installation any way. After installation I discovered I could nolonger see my Backup disk D. All my data was gone. I tried using testdisk but it can't install. What Can I do.Please help me; the data I lost is too much!!!!!!!

Djosh

Comment: Whatever you do, avoid working from Ubuntu installed to your hard disk, but boot from your Ubuntu Live Dvd and post your questions from there. Whatever application (like testdisk) you want to install, install it from the Live DVD and not on your hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

During the installation, did you choose the option-
'**Erase** Everything and install'?

If you did that, then i think your data may be lost.

I dont know much about data recovery, but you should not operate ubuntu from your hard drive to minimise disk changes, and boot from the ubuntu installation disk.

When you boot from it, open the Gparted application, and in the menu bar there is an option -> device -> recover partition table

try that option, maybe it recovers your partitions.

Comment: if Gparted is not able to recover your partition try installing TestDisk within the liveCD as pointed by Emmanuel in the next post by following the testDisk link http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Answer (score 1):

There is a gparted live CD http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php
Maybe you will find the tools you need.

I don't know if gparted still uses "TestDisk" for recovering partition. But in any cases here is the link to the TestDisk documentation. cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk . The "Recovery examples" are worth to read.

As AAditya Baqqa said don't use the Ubuntu you just install, there are chances that you data on D: are untouched. Until recovery uses only live CD.

Answer (score 0):

You may boot your machine with a Ubuntu livecd. After the desktop appears, you will see some disk icons on it. Check the icons to see whether it is the original Windows partition. If so, you can open the icon and recover the data from the partition to another USB disk.